# Updating angular from 1.2 to 1.3 broke my directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have the following directive which I put on input fields that use the angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker:

```
angular.module('directives.validators.date', [])
.directive('validDate',[ '$filter', function ($filter) {
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    require:'ngModel',
    link: function  (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
      var pattern = /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d$/;
      ngModel.scope = scope;
      ngModel.attrs = attrs;
      el.on('blur',function() {
        if(typeof ngModel.$viewValue === "object"){        
          var str = $filter('date')(ngModel.$viewValue, "dd.MM.yyyy");
          ngModel.$setViewValue(str);
        }

        if(ngModel.$viewValue){
          if(ngModel.$viewValue!=="" && !pattern.test(ngModel.$viewValue)){
              ngModel.$setValidity("date",false);
          }
        }
      });

      scope.$watch(function () {
          return ngModel.$modelValue;
        }, 
        function() {
        if(ngModel.$pristine){ //if the data has just been fetched, convert it to date format.
          if (typeof ngModel.$viewValue === "number"){
            var date = new Date(ngModel.$viewValue);
            //var str = $filter('date')(date, "dd.MM.yyyy");
            ngModel.$setViewValue(date);
            ngModel.$setPristine(true);
            var formName = $("form")[0].name;
            ngModel.scope[formName].$setPristine(true);
            ngModel.$setValidity("date",true);
          }
        }
        if(ngModel.$viewValue){ //when the filed is changed, if it is corrected set that the date is valid
          if(ngModel.$viewValue==="" || pattern.test(ngModel.$viewValue)){
            ngModel.$setValidity("date",true); 
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

I had a problem with the datepicker component that my form wouldn't submit if the datepicker field wasn't touched (even if it had data in it, e.g. when I would edit a resource). It basically counted the form as invalid even though a good date was submitted. This directive fixed that, but when I upgraded my angular to 1.3 the directive no longer works.

What would I need to change to get this directive to work again?

Comment: did you upgrade angular-ui also?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Any errors in console? Create some simple plunker that reproduces your problem.

Comment: As I said my form won't submit because it is treated as invalid (even though it is valid, only it isn't touched).

As for angular-ui, the latest version is for angular 1.2, so no version for 1.3 yet.

Comment: @user2352164 I suggest you to check $scope.form object to found what exactly makes the form invalid.

Comment: Have you already checked the [migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-2-to-1-3)? There are quite a few breaking changes in 1.3, but they're (mostly) well documented in the guide.

Comment: a jsbin or something would be nice

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/274e93537ed4e95aefeacea48909eb334894f0ac) you can find something about a breaking change that affects ngModel in 1.3:

> Since the HTML5 pattern validation constraint validates the input value,
>   we should also validate against the viewValue. While this worked in
>   core up to Angular 1.2, in 1.3, we changed not only validation,
>   but the way `input[date]` and `input[number]` are handled - they parse
>   their input values into `Date` and `Number` respectively, which cannot
>   be validated by a regex ...